# link trigger issue

Tags: jquery, events, popup, jquery-events

I have 2 link , l1 ,l2,  if user click on l2 a popup open up ( something like colorbox or lightbox )  and when user click on l1  the ajax request will send to  server and something change in server side.

I want  need one click to if user click on l1 ,open popup and server side effect concurrent occur, every thing is ok if I click them one by one, but I wrote something like this,

```
 $('.hide-sharing').hide();
         
     $(".flag.flag-action").bind('click',function(e){
          //window.location = $(this).next(".hide-sharing").attr('href');
          var text=$(this).attr('href');
          var reg = /(\d+)\?/;
          var arr = text.match( reg );
          var id="#sharing-"+arr[1];
          console.log(id);
                $(id).trigger('click');
        
     });
```

**note:** the first link (flag) is created by system and I can't change it, I want if link1 ( flag class) triggered,  popup opened up.

`<a id="sharing-4029" class="hide-sharing lightbox-processed" rel="lightmodal" href="/share/4029" style="display: none;">sharing</a>`

`<a rel="nofollow" class="flag flag-action flag-link-toggle flag-processed" title="" href="/flag/flag/share/4029?destination=dashboard&amp;token=8WDe0tE-WJNnt9tprwVVmBkdeMa73rGrljW5DdY51yQ">share this item</a>`

where is the problem, does it need to prevent something? something like `e.preventDefault()` in bind click of l2?

```
$('.hide-sharing').bind('click',function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
        });
```

but it is not working.

Comment: So link1 does both actions and link2 only opens the box?

Comment: @trgraglia I want link1 do both

Comment: @trgraglia no it is one link with 2 class